# How can I pass a Tapped event into a XAML template?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I code that I use often in my application so I created this template. With a lot of help from the user gannaway the code I have so far is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
          x:Class="Japanese.SwitchViewCellTemplate"
          x:Name="this">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0" >
      <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference this}}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="✓" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class SwitchViewCellTemplate : ViewCell
    {
        public event EventHandler SelectAction;

        public SwitchViewCellTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(SwitchViewCellTemplate));
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(SwitchViewCellTemplate));

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnTapped()
        {
            base.OnTapped();
            this.SelectAction?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

and the way I would like to use it:

```
<template:SwitchViewCellTemplate Text="{Binding [1].Name}" 
    IsVisible="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" 
    SelectAction="selectValue" />
```

Here is the method used to handle toggled:

```
    void Handle_SelectAction(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var viewCell = sender as ViewCell;
        if (viewCell == null)
            return;
    }
```

Where selectValue is a function in the CS code behind of the pages where I use the template.

The code gives an error:

```
 The type initializer for 'Japanese.SwitchViewCellTemplate' threw an exception.
```

Can anyone give me advice on what might be wrong that is causing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve, an event can be added to the template.

**XAML Template**

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
          x:Class="Japanese.SwitchViewCellTemplate"
          x:Name="this">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0" >
      <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference this}}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="✓" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

**Add an event to your template's code-behind:**

```cs
public partial class SwitchViewCellTemplate : ViewCell
{
    public event EventHandler SelectAction;

    public SwitchViewCellTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Text), 
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(SwitchViewCellTemplate),
            default(string));

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(IsVisible), 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(SwitchViewCellTemplate),
            default(bool));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnTapped()
    {
        base.OnTapped();
        this.SelectAction?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

**Page XAML**

```xaml
<template:SwitchViewCellTemplate Text="{Binding [1].Name}" 
    IsVisible="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" 
    SelectAction="Handle_SelectAction" />
```

**Page Code-Behind**

```cs
    void Handle_SelectAction(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I tried this (updated the question code to be yours also) but it still gives me this error: Templates/SwitchViewCellTemplate.xaml : error : Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: I think the problem might be here:Tapped="{Binding SelectAction, Source={x:Reference this}}"  which is in my XAML template.  Can you confirm that I should or should not have this code in there.  Perhaps you can also to be 100% sure include the XAML for the template that you are suggesting.  Thanks.

Comment: When I remove that Tapped Line from the template it compiles but then I get this error message: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Japanese.SwitchViewCellTemplate' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Not a valid default value
Parameter name: defaultValue

Comment: Do you think having SelectAction="Handle_SelectAction" in the template call that you added is correct?  When I hover over it then it says unknown?

Comment: I added the XAML template.  The original XAML in the question did not compile (it didn't define "this", yet the bindings were referencing "this")

Comment: I made the changes but sorry there's still an issue and it still gives the  error message: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Japanese.SwitchViewCellTemplate' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Not a valid default value Parameter name: defaultValue

Comment: I updated the  template's code-behind as well.  Both BindableProperties were referencing a `typeof(SwitchViewCell)`, but should be `typeof(SwitchViewCellTemplate)`.  I have a working solution, so if you run into more issues, it may be related to other compilation/setup issues.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code but I am still getting the same error.  I updated the question to use all your latest code. Hopefully I have not missed anything.  I will keep looking.

Comment: Thanks, tried it just now and I think it's working.  I will check it out more and if all is okay I will accept your answer later.  Thanks for all the time and help you have put into helping out with this.